# C# - How to clear pending MouseEventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm building an application with a custom scroll wheel. My panels capture the scroll wheel via "panelName.MouseWheel += ..".

But, when the scroll wheel is spammed, it can't update the UI until the scroll wheel stops.

I want to handle one MouseWheel event at a time, removing all MouseWheel events in the queue before handling the current one.

How would I access the "event queue", find specifically the events related to the MouseWheel, then remove them?

Thanks

Comment: In order to achieve this, you can create a custom control that inherits from the Panel class and override its WndProc method to filter out the unwanted MouseWheel events.

Comment: @Bellash Thanks for the suggestion. Hoping for something a more elegant solution though if possible

Comment: It is technically possible if the MouseWheel event handler is too slow, preventing the low-priority paint event from being generated.  Hard to do, human fingers are not that fast.  Add `mainPanel.Update()` to the end of your event handler to force a repaint.  With the side-effect that there are now less mouse events, with bigger Delta values.

Comment: Show the code, so that we can see what you are doing in the handler.  It might be too slow.

Comment: I'm using the G502 mouse, which lets the scroll wheel freely accelerate with one good thrust. Most things can handle a scroll like that, some things can't (like Warzone..)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! That did exactly what I was thinking. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You can use the handled property and set it to true to clear the event.